# Moving Hard Drive between PCs

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive

I know there are duplicate threads with similar questions, but none hit the mark I needed, including the answers on them.

My question is as follows;

I have an oldish laptop that ran Windows XP. The rest of the laptop died, but the HDD is fine, and all data is intact. We'll call this HD1.

If I put this drive is another oldish laptop, with HD2 currently running Windows 7, what might happen?

I know it often takes some configuring to get things to work right when switching hard drives, but what about between operating systems as well?
When I insert my HD2 back into this computer, will everything still be okay, even if HD1 doesn't boot properly?

I have some data I need to recover, but it's not enough information to be worth putting out the effort and money into cloning HD1. HD2 is also very important, and I cannot perform this until I know HD2 will be perfectly okay from the transfer. I pretty much need a few file names, and it's been impossible to get at this drive for a long time.

Comment: The OS that was installed for a different motherboard chipset, will not load. It needs some special treatment first, and i'm nots sure the details re that special treatment but there are threads on it.

Comment: One option is he could plug it in internally, but boot a live OS off a CD, and copy files to a USB stick. Since he said he just needs a file files

Comment: If you SysPrep the Windows XP before you move the HDD, it might work, but technically your Windows license does not allow you to do this.  Which means you will be unable to activate the Windows XP installation.

Comment: In this particular situation HD1 won't boot into Windows when connected to laptop2. However you can use a Live Linux CD to boot with so you can access the HD1 as a storage drive. Connecting HD1 to laptop2 should not interfere with HD2's ability to work properly on laptop2. However if I were you I would probably get a simple SATA to USB adapter cable and use this connect HD1 to laptop2. This would save me all the trouble of moving the HDD that still hold information that is important to me.

Answer (score 4):

If your intent is to place the original hard drive into the laptop, boot it then copy off files you are gonna run into issues where it most likely will not boot due to the hard drive controller being different. Your best bet is to look into a cheap SATA to USB cable. This will allow you to plug the hard drive in as a giant thumb drive essentially and from Windows 7 you can copy over what files you want.

Another option as pointed out by barlop is to boot off of something like a Linux live disc with the XP hard drive attached. You could then mount the hard drive and copy the pertinent files to a USB thumb drive.

Comment: You have not made clear the fact that if he doesn't want to boot it then he can still plug it in internally and access files. The SATA-USB adaptor isn't some special thing that gets around the chipset issue. The chipset issue means he can't boot it

Comment: He stated he was using a laptop to accomplish this. Laptops with dual hard drive slots are few and far between, but if you believe my answer can be made better by stating that, then please edit it and add clarification.

Comment: `Laptops with dual hard drive slots are few`. True, but many still come with an optical drive. Which allows you to replace that with a HDD caddy.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good chance your "HD1" hard drive from an XP machine will not boot or work on a system with a Windows 7 sticker on it for the following reasons:

- XP did not natively support AHCI, or any motherboard RAID, and your Windows 7 may have AHCI or motherboard RAID enabled by default.  This will simply make XP bluescreen on loading wiith an 0x7B error.
- The video driver installed on XP may bluescreen when it loads if the hardware in the system doesn't match, but more likely you'll be dumped into 640x480 VGA compatibility mode.
- If the old laptop was a corporate laptop or had certain types of security software (fingerprint scanners, anything that hooks into the XP login process), that software may not tolerate the sudden changes in hardware and prevent the system from booting.
- If you have a chipset driver installed on XP, it *may* bluescreen when the hardware doesn't match on the Windows 7 system.  This would be more of a problem if your old laptop was a non-Intel chipset and your new laptop is, for example.
- XP may see something it doesn't like in a newer ACPI or BIOS and bluescreen, but I don't think that's particularly likely.
- Any hardware that XP does not have drivers for will not work.  This could be things like your network card, wireless, and even USB controllers.  You may not be able to get working drivers for your Windows 7 hardware under XP, especially the video card at this point.

You can try it, and if it doesn't work, you should be able to replace the original hard drive without issues.  If you change any BIOS settings to try to get it to work, change them back before replacing your original hard drive.

If all you want to do is get files off the old hard drive, a USB adapter or enclosure will be the easiest and won't require you to remove the hard drive in your system at all.

Comment: Not to mention the license will be deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Reckon you could go down the route of a virtual machine? That would enable you to connect the drive using a SATA to USB cabling or attach it to  to get your Windows 7 to recognise it.

Once recognised reckon you could follow this explanation for installing virtual machine using virtual box:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-a-virtual-machine-image-of-your-existing-hard-drive-windows/

Then you can use your windows Xp within your windows 7 and then share files from guest OS to main OS.